# Accessing environment variable through webistrano

Tags: jruby, environment-variables, webistrano

As part of my Webistrano deployment, I need to check if Glassfish home is set on the target  machine.

I've tried the following in jrails.rb, none of which outputs the value of Glassfish home:
echo $GLASSFISH_HOME
echo ['GLASSFISH_HOME']

Of course, glassfish home is set on the target machine (in .bashrc and /etc/profile).
I even tried invoking a script through Webistrano to echo $GLASSFISH_HOME into a file (on target machine). The file does not have the value!

Looks like through Webistrano, I cannot access the local environment of the target machine.

Please help!

Cheers,
Savinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo $GLASSFISH_HOME
As simple as that!!!